# Translate the text error required fields in a form with Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, required

I'm developing an application with Symfony2 and I try to translate texts form validation (required). Validation is done by the browser and I get eg "Veuillez renseigner ce champs" I wish I could translate the customer or switch also navigation.

My forms are made with buidform.

Thank you in advance for your help

Olivier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the browser validation raised when a field has an attribute required, this does not depend on symfony. I'm not sure you can set a language for these messages as they are generated by the user's browser.

A solution for you might be to disable browser validation (ie set `required` to `false` in your formBuilder fields) and rely on Assertions in you entities whose messages you can customise, you'll find more about this [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html).